# How to make a infinite scroll carousel?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, carousel

I'm trying to make a `vertical carousel for a vertical picker` (on React)

I already have the list scrolling, but I want it to be infinite, I mean, when the scroll get the last element then the first element in the list would appear below.

This is how it looks:

[image]

It works with manual scrolling, (I already found some carousels, but those were autoscroll, with keyframe).

**Here is the code**:

```css
:root{

        font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size:33px;
        font-weight: 300;
        /* color: var(--theme-text); */
}

.datePicker-contain {
    position: relative;
    background-color:red;
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}
.datePicker-contain>*::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
    /* width: 0; */
}
.datePicker-contain__viewport {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow:scroll;
/*     scroll-behavior: smooth;
 */    
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;

    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
  
.datePicker-contain__element {
    background-color: rgb(10, 239, 255);
    flex: 0 0 60px;

    /*     width: 100%;*/    
}
  
.datePicker-contain__element:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: rgb(182, 255, 153);
}

.datPicker-containt__snapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    scroll-snap-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="datePicker-contain" >
                <ol class="datePicker-contain__viewport" >
                    <li id="item-picker1" class="datePicker-contain__element">
                        <div class="datPicker-containt__snapper">1</div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="item-picker2"  class="datePicker-contain__element">
                        <div class="datPicker-containt__snapper">2</div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="item-picker3"  class="datePicker-contain__element">
                        <div class="datPicker-containt__snapper">3</div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="item-picker4"  class="datePicker-contain__element">
                        <div className="datPicker-containt__snapper">4</div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="item-picker5"  class="datePicker-contain__element">
                        <div class="datPicker-containt__snapper">5</div>
                    </li>

                </ol>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
isBottom(el) {
  return el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= window.innerHeight;
}

componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('scroll', this.trackScrolling);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.trackScrolling);
}

trackScrolling = () => {
  const wrappedElement = document.getElementById('header');
  if (this.isBottom(wrappedElement)) {
    console.log('header bottom reached');
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
};
```

Check if scroll has reached bottom. If bottom scroll back on top